# Javascript Alert On Successful Form Submission

Tags: javascript, python, django

I am currently using Django 1.9 and Braintree payments JS v3. What I want to be able to do is when the user submits the form successfully, have a Javascript `alert()` pop up. But the pop-up message will be contingent on what the back end Python returns...

So like this:

1. Submit the form
2. Run the backend stuff
3. Pop up the alert with a message dependent on what is returned by the Python backend
4. When the alert is closed, refresh or redirect

   ```
   var client_token = "{{ request.session.braintree_client_token }}"
   var form = document.querySelector('#checkout-form');
   var submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

   braintree.client.create({
           authorization: client_token
       }, function (clientErr, clientInstance) {
           if (clientErr) {  // for error loading client authorization
               if(alert('There was a form verification issue, reloading page on close.')){}
               else window.location.reload();
               return;
           }

           braintree.hostedFields.create({
               client: clientInstance,
               styles: {
                   'input': {
                       'font-size': '14px'
                   },
                   'input.invalid': {
                       'color': 'red'
                   },
                   'input.valid': {
                       'color': 'green'
                   }
               },
               fields: {
                   number: {
                       selector: '#card-number',
                       placeholder: 'Credit Card Number'
                   },
                   cvv: {
                       selector: '#cvv',
                       placeholder: '123'
                   },
                   expirationDate: {
                       selector: '#expiration-date',
                       placeholder: '10/2019'
                   },
                   postalCode: {
                       selector: '#postal-code',
                       placeholder: '10014'
                   }
               }
           }, function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance) {
               if (hostedFieldsErr) {  // for errors creating form
                   if(alert('There was a form creation issue, reloading page on close.')){}
                   else window.location.reload();
                   return;
               }

               submit.removeAttribute('disabled');

               form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
                   event.preventDefault();
                   document.querySelector('input[id="pay-button"]').value = "Please wait...";

                   hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
                       if (tokenizeErr) {
                           if (tokenizeErr.code === 'HOSTED_FIELDS_FIELDS_EMPTY') {
                               alert('Please fill in card info');
                               document.querySelector('input[id="pay-button"]').value = "Complete Booking";
                           }
                           return;
                       }
                       // Put `payload.nonce` into the `payment_method_nonce`
                       document.querySelector('input[name="payment_method_nonce"]').value = payload.nonce;
                       form.submit();
                       $('input[type="submit"]').prop('disabled',true);
                   });
               }, false);
           });
       });
   ```

I'm thinking that this functionality would need to be right after `form.submit()` is run on the bottom...

**Edit:**

I added the vars up top in my code

Comment: It looks like your code has an infinite loop. In your form submission handler, you are calling form.submit(), which will trigger the submission handler again.

Comment: Braintree hijacks the `submit` of the form, that's their own submit so it'll only be called once.

Comment: Braintree does not hijack the `submit` of the form, the "hijacking" is happening in the `form.addEventListener` and is preventing the default action to occur with `event.preventDefault()`

Comment: Ah, thank you for the correction.

Comment: Have you tried removing `form.submit();` and replacing it with `alert(...);`? alerts are synchronous so the code after it will not be executed until it is closed

Comment: Well I want the form to submit so that way I can tell if the credit card was declined or not... maybe what I can do is if the card is declined (determined by my Python backend) is re-render the one with an alert variable (like a 1 or a 0 for true or false) and inside my HTML, put an '{% if alert %}' and then just have the pop-up come up and refresh the page when it's closed? I want to be able to achieve this though without refreshing the page first...